# Trying to convert a list of date(actrived from database) to format(yyyy-mm)

Tags: java

```
public List<Date> getDate(){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> cr =          (List<String>)getSession().createCriteria(OrderEntity.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Property.forName("ordertime"))
                    )
            .list();
    System.out.println("zxcv");
    System.out.println(cr);//the output is here [2017-10-23 15:15:53.0, 2017-10-25 11:53:56.0, 2017-10-25 11:54:35.0}
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList(cr.size());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm");
    for (String dateString : cr) {
        dates.add(sdf.parse(dateString));
    }
    System.out.println(dates);
    return dates;
}
```

There is the error :

> java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.String.

Please tell me how to solve this error,
thank you so much.

Comment: on which line you are getting this error.

Comment: hi,  i got the error from here -- [for (String dateString : cr) ]

Comment: I'm trying to convert the output up there to this format "yyyy-mm"

Comment: Thank u for your help

Comment: Please use the new Data API of Java, the class `Date` is **legacy**, use `LocalDate` and the other classes in the `java.time` package.

Comment: @Zabuza I get it now, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database engine already knows that your dates are dates and not strings. `println()` uses `toString()` for your array elements, so you won't see that. Change the spec to `List<Timestamp>` from `List<String>` and instead of

```
for (String dateString : cr) {
    dates.add(sdf.parse(dateString));
}
```

do

```
for (Timestamp ts : cr) {
    dates.add(new Date(ts.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: hi , ur solution works without error,but how to convert the dates to this format "yyyy-mm", right now the output is like this  [2017-10-23 15:15:53.0, 2017-10-25 11:53:56.0]. Thank u for ur help

Comment: If you want formatted dates, then take a look at `SimpleDateFormat`. You used it to **parse** dates, but it can also **format** dates.

Comment: I get it.Thank u very much